# Team Build TF10122 error when using $(BuildAgentId)

Tags: msbuild, build-automation, tfsbuild

I am trying to use the this Build Agent Folder for my build definition...

> $(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\VPB

... but I get the following error.

> TF10122: The path 'c:\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\VPB' contains a '$' at
>   the beginning of a path component. Remove the '$' and try again.

I need to include something to denote the agent because I have two build agents on the build server.

I am trying to keep the path short, because InstallShield has unreasonably long path names for merge modules (too many subfolders and adds GUIDS to the ends of everything).

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Are you trying to use this from within TFS-Build, or with MSbuild? In case you 're doing it from within TFS, you could simply use the variable `BuildDirectory` which resolves during build into your "C:\Builds\123\VPB"

Comment: AFAIK, that still causes workspace collision with multiple build agents.

Comment: No, it shouldn't - since `$(BuildAgentId)` gets resolved into the actual ID during runtime & TFSBuild holds that within `BuildDirectory`.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your Build Definition and Build Agent working directory are setup correctly.

[Setting up build agent working directory and build definition working directories](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2007/08/14/tfs-2008-a-basic-guide-to-team-build-2008.aspx)

Comment: I can tweak the path in the agents to use definition ID, but I am more interested in why this variable isn't working.

Comment: By setting your agent up to use a path like $(SystemDrive)\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath) it ensures there will be no work-space mapping issues or other builds that map to the same location. That is why it is important to use $(sourcedir) as well in your build definitions work-space. Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess trying to use the build agent ID variable is only valid on the build agent? I cant find any clear documentation as to what variable is allowed where.

Comment: You can use two types of tokens directory Tokens or environment variables. The environment variables are based off the user account logged in.

For example, you have configured Team Foundation Build Service to run under an account that is called BuildSvcAcct. You specify $(HomeDrive)\Builds as the working directory for a build agent on a build machine that is running Windows Server 2008. As a result, the build agent will typically use, as its working directory, a physical directory that approximates the following location: C:\Builds.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399135.aspx

Comment: The point of the issue is that I expect to use a variable (listed on the page you just linked, from the section starting "Team Foundation Build variables: You can use the following variables in a build agent working directory...") in the Build Definition--> Workspace --> Build Agent Folder value and it doesn't work. Apparently these variables are not available to any other build agent modules outside of the Build Agent properties dialog box.

Comment: These variables are environment variables set each time a build is ran. Using environment specific variables that get set during the build run have no effect for other builds. This gives you the advantage of being able to run a build and set the environment variable for the build run and not effecting other build definitions run on other machines. Basically the scope is limited to the time and exact build you run.

Comment: I don't think you are getting my meaning. I don't have a question about what environment variables are or what they are good for. I do have a question about why this one works in one place and does not in another seemingly equal place (the build uses both at just about the same time). If its due to a bug or design decision that's fine. But if its not and I am being thick-headed about some concept, I just want to know what I am missing.